# Colouring 3D objects

Tags: opengl-es, colors, 3d, pandaboard

I have many objects in my scene and I want to colour every object with different colours. Now, my fragment shader consists of :

```
void main (void)\
{\
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.82, 0.41, 0.12 ,1.0);\
}";
```

and the vertex shader consists of :

```
attribute highp vec4    myVertex;\
uniform mediump mat4    myPMVMatrix;\

void main(void)\
{\
gl_Position = myPMVMatrix * myVertex;\
}";
```

and hence it colours each object with the same colour. Can anyone tell how can I colour differently ? I have prepared a 2D array consisting of the colours for all the objects. I can't figure out how to pass them to the fragment shader or how to change the fragment shader and vertex shader code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to color objects individually is to pass a uniform (like you did with `myPMVMatrix`) containing the color you want, for each object.
You would have a `uniform vec4 objectColor` in the fragment shader that you can directly use inf `gl_FragColor`.

The fragment shader would look like:

```
uniform mediump vec4 myColor;\
void main (void)\
{\
     gl_FragColor = myColor;\
}";
```

and you would pass it exactly like you passed your `myPMVMatrix`, just with the word `myColor` instead of `myPMVMatrix`.

Comment: How will the vertex shader and fragment shader code change. Can you explain by writing both the shader's code ? Also, how will I pass the colour from my main function ?

Comment: I passed the matrix by : 

int i32Location = glGetUniformLocation(m_uiProgramObject, "myPMVMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, PMVMatrix.ptr());

But, doesn't this pass the matrix to the vertex shader ? Don't I have to use a variable myColor in vertex shader also ?

Comment: you don't need to : the glGetUniformLocation can find the location of a variable in a fragment shader as well. If you just do a glGetUniformLocation(m_uiProgramObject, "myColor"); and glUniform3fv(...) this should send your variable to the correct shader.